# SpringBoot + Springfox swagger3 + @RequestBody - skipping endpoint as it has an error

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have a problem with springfox and swagger 3:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

with spring boot 2.7.4. Other endpoints with @RequestParams work fine, but I have two post requests with @RequestBody:

```
public class UpdateIndexRequestDto {

    private Integer clientId;
    private String documentSignature;
    private String segmentSignature;
    private String source;
    private String target;
    private String sourcePlain;
}
```

Typical dto class with getters, setters, noArgsConstructor and AllArgsConstructor. Endpoint method below:

```
@PostMapping("/addIndex")
public OperationResponseDto addIndex (@RequestParam Integer clientId,
    @RequestParam Integer sourceLangCode,
    @RequestParam Integer targetLangCode,
    @RequestBody UpdateIndexRequestDto requestDto)
{
```

and at last the error that I receive when starting the application:

```
'''022-11-19 22:10:02.464 ERROR 18352 --- [           main] 
s.d.s.web.scanners.ApiDescriptionReader  : Skipping process path[/tm/test/addIndexes], 
method[addIndexes] as it has an error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/event/Level
at springfox.documentation.builders.ValidationResult.<init>(ValidationResult.java:12) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.builders.ModelSpecificationBuilder.validateSpecification(ModelSpecificationBuilder.java:243) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.builders.ModelSpecificationBuilder.build(ModelSpecificationBuilder.java:293) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.builders.SimpleParameterSpecificationBuilder.build(SimpleParameterSpecificationBuilder.java:173) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
at springfox.documentation.builders.RequestParameterBuilder.build(RequestParameterBuilder.java:165) ~[springfox-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]'''
```

What am I missing? There are many different solutions with annotations, but nothing seems to work. I've spend a lot of time debugging this, to at least find what causes the problem.

Comment: it looks like an issue with that springFox version. maybe you can change the version and retry. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3514

Comment: I would suggest to use springdoc-openapi instead of springfox as it is a much more recent library. The migration from springfox is straight-forward. See https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Comment: Do you have log4j added as a dependency? can you also post your pom.xml file?